# Frustum near plane OpenGL makes object appear closer, instead of just clipping

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, frustum

In openGles decreasing the frustum near plane (as you see [here](http://relativity.net.au/gaming/java/Frustum.html)) makes the objects appear closer. I come from 3d where for example in Vray, changing the near clip plane doesn't modify the distance and just clips some geometry.

Why changing the near plane of the frustum makes the object appear closer?

Comment: Changing the distance to the near clip plane does not make appear objecst closer or farther away. So the question is what you actually change if it has this effect. Whithout more details, nobody can tell you.

Comment: @derhass: My guess is, that OP keeps the left, right, top, bottom values constant, so varying the near clip plane distance alters the field of view.

Comment: @datenwolf: that was my first guess too, but decreasing the near plane distance and keeping the other parameters should increase the FOV, so the object should appear _smaller_.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that changing the frustum has the effect described [here.](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml)

So according to the docs, when you call this function

```
void glFrustum(GLdouble  left,  GLdouble  right,  GLdouble  bottom,  GLdouble  top,  GLdouble  nearVal,  GLdouble  farVal);
```

what you're doing is multiplying the current projection matrix by a matrix built from the values specified in the parameters.

If you take a look at how that matrix is built, you will notice that it is very similar to a scaling matrix. The element at 3,3 (which goes by the name of `C` in the doc page) is equal to `-(far+near)/(far-near)`. This means that if you decrease `near` and leave `far` as it is, `C` will get closer to zero. When the matrix multiplication takes place, this will act like a downscaling of the Z coordinate.

So when you decrease the near value, the vertices will appear as though they have been brought closer to the origin proportionally to their Z coordinate. This decrease also has an effect on the X and Y coordinates, of course, and should make the objects look more "compressed" towards the center. I guess that effect is more consistent with what we intuitively expect from bringing the near clipping plane closer to the point of view.